# Extracting hidden representations for each token - PyTorch LSTM

Tags: nlp, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working on a NLP project involving recurrent neural networks. I implemented a LSTM with PyTorch, following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/word_language_model).

For my project, I need to extract the hidden representation for every token of an input text. I thought that the easiest way would be to test using a batch size and sequence length of 1, but when I do that the loss gets orders of magnitude larger than in training phase (during training I used a batch size of 64 and a sequence length of 35).

Is there any other way I can easily access these word-level hidden representations? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible with nn.LSTM as long as it is a single layer LSTM. If u check the documentation ([here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html)), for the output of an LSTM, you can see it outputs a tensor and a tuple of tensors. The tuple contains the hidden and cell for the last sequence step. What each dimension means of the output depends on how u initialized your network. Either the first or second dimension is the batch dimension and the rest is the sequence of word embeddings you want.

If u use a packed sequence as input, it is a bit of a different story.